# What is the semantic for the modulo operator x % y, when y is 0?

Tags: c, operators, semantics, modulus, modular-arithmetic

Suppose I try to perform the following:

```
y = 0;
z = x % y;
```

is the semantic for this well-defined, platform-dependent, or undefined? I'm asking mainly about C/C++, but am interested in the answer for various programming/scripting languages (Java, perl, sh, etc.)

I'm asking partly because there are [different](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/516251/22998) [possible](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=87384) ways to define the modulo operation: As [the remainder of a division operation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/516255/22998); as the [size of a quotient group](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/516256/22998), etc.

Comment: You get a `ZeroDivisionError` in Python.

Comment: Now (after edit) it's a different question, more suitable for Math.SE, I suppose. In fact, there's [one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516251/why-is-n-mod-0-undefined) already.

Comment: @raina77ow: I was just justifying why it's not entirely trivial that the semantic would be the same as division by zero. I really just want to know what the different language specs say.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Behaviour is undefined for C.

From *C11 6.5.5 Multiplicative operators*, p5

> The result of the / operator is the quotient from the division of the
>   first operand by the second; the result of the % operator is the
>   remainder. In both operations, if the value of the second operand is
>   zero, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: +1, one should perhaps add that it only stated as clearly in C11, in C99 this was only implicit.

Comment: Note another relevant paragraph in the same section (a bit rephrased) - `When integers are divided, if the quotient a/b is not representable, the behavior of both a/b and a%b is
undeﬁned.`

Answer (score 1):

It's well defined for [**JavaScript**](http://es5.github.io/#x11.5.3):

> The result of an ECMAScript floating-point remainder operation is
> determined by the rules of IEEE arithmetic: [...]
>
> If the dividend is an infinity, **or the divisor is a zero**, or both, the
> result is `NaN`.

---

Now about the other languages. The common approach ([**Java**](http://ideone.com/X0GhzR), [**C#**](http://ideone.com/yMneD4), [**Python**](http://ideone.com/cv1lWj), [**Ruby**](http://ideone.com/JVcMiM)) is to throw some kind of `ZeroDivisionError` at you when you attempt to evaluate `somenum % 0` expression.

For Perl, it's a bit more interesting:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper 0 % 0;
print 'Something else';
```

Now, this code results in `Illegal modulus zero` error; but had you put `0 / 0` instead, you would have seen `Illegal division by zero` message. Both are errors (stop execution of the remaining code), of course, not warnings.

---

Now PHP chooses a bit different stance on this:

```
var_dump(0 % 0); // it's the same for any numeric dividend
// Warning: Division by zero in ...
// bool(false)
```

As you see, you get `false` (sic) as a result, but warning [**is triggered**](https://eval.in/65688). It's ignorable, though; have you set `error_reporting` level to `E_ERROR`, you wouldn't have even seen it.

Comment: So, it's NaN even if the operands are integers? (Yeah, I know JavaScript is duck-typed)?

Comment: Ah, I see your point. Yes, `Number % Number` gives you `NaN` - but guess what, `typeof NaN` gives you `'number'`. )

Answer (score 0):

in Java, if you try to compile

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 10,y,z;
    y = 0;
    z = x % y;
    System.out.println("Z: " + z);
}
```

You will get this message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at locationConfiguration.LocationConfigurator.main
```

so, you won't be able to do modulo zero.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  int x = 10,y,z;
  y = 0;
  z = x % y;
  System.out.println("Z: " + z);
}

i used that as code and received that error message

Comment: 'try to compile' is a bit incorrect choice of words. The code compiles fine; the exception will be thrown when one _runs_ the program.

Comment: sorry raina77ow. Still kind of new to this site. I'm trying to improve my descriptions =)!